# Pimpl and pointers in the implementation of the private class

Tags: c++, qt, pimpl-idiom

I have the following Pimpl class where one of the member in the `FooPrivate` class is a pointer to a class A that should be dynamically allocated in `Foo:init()` and destroy in `Foo:stop()` or in the dtor of `Foo`. So far i have this :

foo.h :

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <QtGlobal>

class FooPrivate;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    void init(); // here we should dynamically instanciate an object of class A

    ~Foo();

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Foo)
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Foo)
    FooPrivate * const d_ptr;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

foo.cpp :

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo_p.h"
#include "a.h"

Foo::Foo()
    : d_ptr(new FooPrivate)
{
    Q_D(Foo);

    d->a = nullptr; 
}

void Foo::init()
{
    Q_D(Foo);

    if (d->a) // init should happen only once
        return;

    // and d->a should be instanciated here
    d->a = new A;
}

void Foo::stop()
{
    Q_D(Foo);

    delete d->a;
    d->a = nullptr;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    Q_D(Foo);        

    delete d->a;
    delete d_ptr;
}
```

foo_p.h :

```
#ifndef FOOPRIVATE_H
#define FOOPRIVATE_H

class Foo;
class A;

struct FooPrivate
{
    FooPrivate() {}

    A *a;
};

#endif // FOOPRIVATE_H
```

My concern is about the ownership of `A *a` and where the allocation should take place in the code ? in `Foo` class or in `FooPrivate` ?

Is it more clean to create helper functions like `FooPrivate::init()` and `FooPrivate::stop()` that will be call from `Foo:init()` and `Foo:stop()`, and also delete `A *a` in the dtor of `FooPrivate` instead ?

Thank you.

Comment: where did `d` come from?

Comment: From the `Q_D()` (it's a Qt macro)

Answer (score 1):

> My concern is about the ownership of A *a

Then use a smart pointer, something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a;
```